# Properties cannot be loaded after InputStream read

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/prop.txt");

//Read the content
byte[] bys = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len=fis.read(bys))!=-1) {
  System.out.println(new String(bys));
}

//Load the properties and print
prop.load(fis);
fis.close();
System.out.println(prop);
```

The src/prop.txt is simple as:

```
city=LA
country=USA
```

It prints out nothing in the prop, meaning the prop is empty:

```
{}
```

But if I remove the part of reading, prop can be loaded as:

```
{country=USA, city=LA}
```

Why is it failed to fulfill the prop after reading the content of prop.txt?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to load the key-value pairs to prop. But prop is empty if I read the content of the prop.txt. If I don't read them, it's loaded. I wonder why.

Comment: You have a typo after `System.out.println(new String(bys))`, there should be a `;` insated of `'` at the end.

Comment: It was a type. I corrected it.

Comment: you have a `*Stream`, that is, a **sequence** of bytes - once you read it, you cannot just re-read it (without jumping back [if possible]) || you could use a `FilterInputStream` and *divert* the bytes into an array while reading the Properties; or use the byte array to create a `ByteArrayInputStream` to read the Properties from.

Comment: Just get rid of the loop that prints the `InputStream` to `System.out`. This is the problem, and you don't need it.

Comment: I know the loop is not needed here. But the point is that I'd like to know WHY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read the stream, the stream pointer points to the end of the stream. After that when `prop.load()` try to read from the stream, nothing more is available. You have to call [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()) on the stream before reading it again.

```
Properties prop = new Properties(); 
BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/prop.txt"));

fis.mark(fis.available())  //set marker at the begining


//Read the content
byte[] bys = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len=fis.read(bys))!=-1) {
  System.out.println(new String(bys));
}

fis.reset(); //reset the stream pointer to the begining

//Load the properties and print
prop.load(fis);
fis.close();
System.out.println(prop);
```

Comment: Thx. But it got IOexception: mark/reset not supported

Comment: Sorry for missing that out. You can use [BufferedInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496172/is-there-a-way-to-create-fileinputstream-with-mark-feature) instead

Comment: `reset()` does not 'reset the stream pointer to the beginning', and it will do exactly nothing without a prior `mark()` even when supported. Don't post guesswork here.

Comment: added `mark()` in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I looked it up once but forget about the usage of mark. But I did remember the document says `the stream is reset to a state such that all the bytes read since the most recent call to mark (or since the start of the file, if mark has not been called)`. May I ask about under what circumstances could it fall into `"since the start of the file, if mark has not been called"`, if this is not the case?

Comment: Well, Ricky's answer got the point, which revealed the stream pointer thing that I didn't know before. The mark/reset thing, honestly, I'm not interested, but good to know anyway (they need to be  used together like a pair). Salute to you guys!

Answer (score 1):

> It prints out nothing in the prop, meaning the prop is empty:

Because you have already gone through the data available in your input stream `fis`, by `fis.read(bys)` in your `while` condition (see what actually `read​(byte[] b)` [does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D))), and there is nothing left when you're loading it into your properties.

`FileInputStream` is not a type that holds the data persistently; it's rather an object, that represents a pipe, a *connection* to the file descriptor, and data flows from the file, byte by byte, as long as you keep calling `.read(..)` on it.

Also, read [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader

Comment: Thx! Good to know more about the input stream thing.

Answer (score -1):

Better use ResourceBundle for loading the properties file. Assuming that you are using maven, you can place the properties file name application.properties in the folder "src/main/resources" and you load and using below code:

```
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
    String value = resourceBundle.getString("key");
```

Please refer to the javadocs of [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for more details.

More examples at https://mkyong.com/java/java-resourcebundle-example/ or https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle

Comment: I'd like to know why it failed to load the properties if I read the txt file. It loaded fine without reading the file. I don't see why reading the file can fail the properties loading.