# Upload large size( >1GB) file to server using java

Tags: java, file-upload

I want to upload large file (any format) more than 1GB. what technique I will use FTP or HTTP. And I want to add stop and resume feature to file i am  uploading. How can I do that? Any example or API or library?

Comment: Refer [here][1]

Its done using plupload. Hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074516/how-could-i-upload-a-large-file-in-chunks-using-java?s=2%7C1.7848

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons net has an FTP-client. And some other protocol implementations.
http://commons.apache.org/net/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the default HttpUrlConnection or Apache HttpClient.

Comment: which will be best as I want to upload large size file and it should be faster

Comment: @amrit_neo - it probably makes little difference.  The network and disc / file system bandwidth will probably be the limiting factors.  But feel free to implement both to see which works best for you ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this library, it contains all your desired features:

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

Answer (score 1):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074516/how-could-i-upload-a-large-file-in-chunks-using-java?s=2%7C1.7848)

I have done it using plupload. Hope it helps you. Any number of files of any sizes can be uploaded using it..