# Implementing large file uploads via HTTP

Tags: java, http, tomcat, file-upload

I need to create a web application based on Apache Tomcat, which can receive large (100 MB or more) files via HTTP (multipart form POST request).

I tried Apache Commons Fileupload and it works for smaller files (20-40 MB). But it doesn't work for large files.

Are there any obvious ways to implement large file upload except

1. using Java applet at the client side,
2. tweaking Tomcat's settings?

**Update 1 (03.10.2013):** Here's the exception that I get at the server side when uploading 2 files with approx. 120 total size.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Are you sure exactly what does not work? Client-side error? Server rejecting the upload? Network problem?

Comment: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

Comment: @Thilo See screenshot with the exception in update 1.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Commons Fileupload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another solution. On the FileUpload's web site there is a [page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) about the Streaming API.

The code snippet on that page solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a error in tomcat you could increase the maximum upload file size and the maximum request size in your `web.xml`.

An example with 50MB max upload:

```
<multipart-config>
    <!-- 50MB max -->
    <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

If you have an apache or nginx infront of your tomcat as proxy, you may have to increase their upload/post size values too in the server config.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `maxPostSize` attribute value of the HTTP connector in your Tomcat `server.xml` config file:

```
<Connector port="8080" ... maxPostSize="<high_file_size_value>" ...>
```

Tomcat reference doc: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074516/how-could-i-upload-a-large-file-in-chunks-using-java/29523375#29523375)

It can be done using plupload. In case you dont want to use applet, you can use flash,html5 etc.. Any number of files of any size can be uploaded.