# How to upload file (100MB to 1 GB) in server using java multithreading concept?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, spring-mvc

I implemented uploading functionality in my project using spring and web services.
I am able to upload a 30MB file but it takes time to upload.
Now I want to upload a file bigger than 100MB but in less time.
What should I do?
How can I do it using multi threading?

Comment: I doubt multi-threading would change anything. You probably have a bandwidth problem, not a CPU problem.

Comment: Than, How could I implement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing large file uploads via HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158118/implementing-large-file-uploads-via-http)

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading is almost certainly useless. Parallelism only helps if you can spread the slow part of your work out, and in file transfers, the limiting factor is nearly always either network bandwidth or disk speed.