# File Upload Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to upload a file in chunks in Java.
My chunk upload function:

```
@Async
private Future<String> sendChunk(byte[] chunk, int start, int end, int numberOfChunks, String name, String sessionId) throws IOException {

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestParams.add("data", new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(chunk), "UTF-8"));
    requestParams.add("start", start);
    requestParams.add("end", end);
    requestParams.add("numberOfChunks", numberOfChunks);
    requestParams.add("fileName", name);
    requestParams.add("session", sessionId);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestParams);
    UploadResponse uploadResponse = restTemplate.exchange(fileServiceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<UploadResponse>(){}).getBody();
    return new AsyncResult<>(uploadResponse.getSessionId());
}
```

This is how the File-Service-API looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simpleUploader", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> simpleUploader(
    @RequestParam("data") String data,
    @RequestParam("session") String sessionId,
    @RequestParam("start") int start,
    @RequestParam("end") int end,
    @RequestParam("numberOfChunks") int numberOfChunks,
    @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    ....
}
```

Now, if I try to upload a Chunk the File-Service responds with a `400 - Bad Request`.
Stack-Trace:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
>       at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:526)

It will be rejected from Spring even before it gets to the API-Function.
I am already uploading the same way, but in Javascript. From Javascript everything is working as it should.
What am I missing?

Comment: chech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074516/how-could-i-upload-a-large-file-in-chunks-using-java/29523375#29523375 might help.

Comment: for what exactly?

Comment: another way of uploading using pl upload in chunks.

Comment: @AshutoshJha i am actually using a "standard" multipart file upload mechanism. dont know why i should change my (working) implementation.

Comment: thats why i said might help not it will definitely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I had with my code was, that "sessionId" will be `null` the first time I am calling the File-Service API.
When I set a value of a Map Entry to null, the whole Entry doesn't get passed. I didnt knew that.
My fix was to add a `defaultValue` to `@RequestParam("session") String sessionId` so that the method declaration looks like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simpleUploader", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<UploadResponse> simpleUploader(
    ...
    @RequestParam(value = "session", defaultValue = "") String sessionId,
    ... ) throws IOException {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well if it works, it works. But I would rather have a mechanism in place that ensures a session exists before any logic is invoked that relies on there being a session.

Comment: initially there is no session available. the first chunk is the "handshake"  between client and server. when the first chunk gets uploaded, the server will create a session for the rest of the file chunks.

Answer (score 0):

The @Async has two limitations.

- it must be applied to public methods only.
- self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Try changing `private` to `public`

`@Async
public Future<String> sendChunk(byte[] chunk, int start, int end, int numberOfChunks, String name, String sessionId) throws IOException {`