# Java: fseek(), ftell() equivalents for text file input?

Tags: java, file

How can I seek into a text file in Java?  I'm processing a text-based journal file, and would like to checkpoint my work so that it can be resumed by a future invocation of my program.

I'm looking for something similar to C stdio fseek()/ftell() functionality.

Comment: closely related, [java file input with rewind()/reset() capability]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094703/java-file-input-with-rewind-reset-capability) - for the generic byte stream case though, multi-byte characters can add quite a bit of complexity on top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) gives you random access to a file (surprise, surprise :)) and its `readLine()` method allows you to process it line by line.

The current position can be queried by `getFilePointer()` and the `seek()` method seeks.